# How to make a div scroll able when window height is reached

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, overflow

I have developed a template using bootstrap, the following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aaLuzkur/) represents the layout expected, where i want the yellow area to be scroll able when the content inside reaches window height, while the right red panel remains fixed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
Header
</div>

<div class="content">

  <div class="left-panel">
      <div class="dummy-content">
          Results
      </div>
       <div class="dummy-content">
          Results
      </div>
       <div class="dummy-content">
          Results
      </div>
       <div class="dummy-content">
          Results
      </div>
      <div class="dummy-content">
          Results
      </div>
       <div class="dummy-content">
          Results
      </div>
       <div class="dummy-content">
          Results
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-panel">
    Map
  </div>

</div>

<div class="footer">
Footer
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.header{
  background:black; 
  color:#fff;}

.left-panel{
    background:yellow;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}
.dummy-content{
    height:150px;
}
.right-panel{
    background:tomato;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}

.footer{
  background:grey;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
 }      

.content > div{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.content{
  clear:both;
}
```

My problem is

- how to make the content inside scroll when content increase and once window height is reached
- the footer should not overlap the scroll able area when screen size is changed
- is it possible to provide a css fix only

Comment: your fiddle is empty

Comment: Thank you @Vitorinofernandes its updated now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `calc()` function and `vh` units to achieve the desired output :

```
.left-panel{
  background:yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:calc(100vh - 40px);
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aaLuzkur/2/)

Answer (score 1):

`overflow` needs `height` to be set. Set child's `height` to 0 and also make it `grow` inside the parent.

```
.parent{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   height:100%
}

.child{
   flex-grow:1;
   height:0;
   overflow:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Fiddle is empty. You can try the code below:

```
div{   
overflow:auto;
}
```

or

```
div{   
overflow-wrap:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on the parent div, try to use

```
.left-panel
{
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

also, make sure to give a fixed position to the div